# org-agenda won't show up when entries have timestamp with time range

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, timestamped

been using org-mode for quite a while now (native emacs 26 on win10). Since yesterday, my org-agenda won't show up anymore if there is an entry to be displayed with an *active timestamp* that has a *time range* in the simple format (e.g. <2021-05-17 Mo 14:00-15:30>). There's no problem with either 'Deadline' or 'Scheduled' entries and also the format <2021-05-17 Mo 14:00>--<2021-05-17 Mo 15:30> works (but is kind of inconvenient...)

I get the following error message: `org-duration-to-minutes: Invalid duration format: #("14:00-15:30" 0 11 (fontified t line-prefix #("**" 0 2 (face org-indent)) wrap-prefix #("***** " 0 2 (face org-indent) 2 6 (face org-indent)) face org-date mouse-face highlight keymap (keymap (follow-link . mouse-face) (mouse-3 . org-find-file-at-mouse) (mouse-2 . org-open-at-mouse)) org-category "Lehre"))`

I have no idea if it's a bug or if it's a problem of my configuration...

Comment: I believe this bug was introduced recently and has already been fixed. Please update your Org mode (again).

Comment: Thank you! It's fixed now!